# SQL Server 2016 - Moving table across schemas - Error: Cannot transfer the object

Tags: sql-server, schema

Before posting this, I searched both on Stack Overflow and the web in general.

My task is simple: I would like to move table A from schema X to schema Y. When trying it out like this:

```
ALTER SCHEMA Y TRANSFER X.A
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot transfer the object 'A', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

- I checked multiple times that both the schemas and the table exist
- Environment: SQL Server 2016
- Table A was copied over from a different database on a different server, using SQL Server Export/Import wizard
- I have similar permissions on both schemas
- All permissions are inherited via an Active Directory group
- Earlier in the day, I executed the same command for a different table and it worked perfectly fine.
- Table A contains nearly 280 million rows. So copying via temp table or table scripting is not efficient
- The MSDN article mentions that "*To transfer a securable from another schema, the current user must have CONTROL permission on the securable (not schema) and ALTER permission on the target schema*"
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

- I am not sure how to check for CONTROL permission. I tried `sp_table_privileges` and `fn_my_permissions`. Could not find anything useful.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Who owns the table?  eg

```
select s.name schema_name, 
       t.name table_name, 
       user_name(coalesce(t.principal_id,s.principal_id)) owner_name
from sys.tables t
join sys.schemas s 
  on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
```

You check your permissions with

```
select *
from sys.fn_my_permissions('X.A','OBJECT')
```

Comment: 1) Owner of the table is dbo - just like all other tables in that database.
2) At the table level, I've the following permissions: SELECT, UPDATE, REFERENCES, INSERT, DELETE, VIEW DEFINITION, ALTER. This seems to be the same for all other tables.

Comment: You need to have an ALTER ANY SCHEMA privilege to do so and also a CONTROL over  the objects.

Comment: You only need ALTER on the target schema.